# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update of one column only

Tags: mysql

I'd like to be able to update the column set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP only when one particular other column is updated, rather than the whole row. For example in a table with columns like `status,some_other_col,updated_on`, I need the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in the `updated_on` column to change only when the value in `status` changes, and stay the same when the changes are made on `some_other_col`. Would that be possible and if yes, what would be the right syntax of the query?

Comment: You could use a trigger for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE TRIGGER updtrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
     IF NEW.status <> OLD.status THEN
     SET NEW.updated_on = NOW();     
     END IF;
     END
     //
```

Comment: Worked (almost) like a charm. Just had to struggle a bit through `1235 This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'` since I am new to triggers (and SQL more advanced than SELECT and UPDATE as such). But in the end, inserting the trigger into the query itself after the UPDATE did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Inverbis,
I too want to achieve the same thing.could you please let me know the actual code you used to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can update updated_on column after you update status column. It's easy to manage.If you change your datasource, you may rewrite the trigger.